# How can I check my battery health (do I need a new battery)?

Tags: battery, battery-life

Is there a way to see if my android phone needs to have it's battery replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into Google Play store and download a Battery Manager, most of them show some information, for example how fast battery is draining, also the temperature and other stuff, also it can tell you the battery state/quality